# How can I use Scrapy to get a json object in a <script> tag

Tags: javascript, json, scrapy, splash-screen

I've run into a script tag in the head of a page.  Inside this tag is a json object that I'd like to extract.  However, it seems like I'll need to use splash or one of the other few html rendering libraries.

Looking for some thoughts... Here's a bit of the page.

```
<script>
window.appData = {
    "ressSize": "large",
    "cssPath": "http://css.bbystatic.com/",
    "imgPath": "http://images.bbystatic.com/",
    "jsPath": "http://js.bbystatic.com/",
    "bbyDomain": "http://www.bestbuy.com/",
    "bbySslDomain": "https://www-ssl.bestbuy.com/",
    "isUserLoggedIn": false,
    "zipCode": "46801",
    "stores": [{
        "id": "2727",
        "name": "GLENBROOK SQUARE",
        "addr1": "4201 coldwater rd",
        "addr2": "spc g10",
        "city": "fort wayne",
        "state": "IN",
        "country": "US",
        "zipCode": "46805",
        "phone": "260-482-5230"...
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "extract"? What are you trying to do with that JS object?

Comment: You could use a regular expression to fetch the json inside the tag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json

Comment: Is it a different question than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39895427/how-do-i-extract-a-jsonobj-out-of-a-javascript-with-scrapy ?